# Why TcpListener does not implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, idisposable, tcplistener

To better understand how the .NET networking part works, I'm going through the reference source of the TcpListener([Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx), [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/TCPListener.cs,ad615384c4805213)) class. What caught my attention is that it owns the object implementing IDisposable (Socket) but does not implement IDisposable itself. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: IMO, there is no such a reason. Just a developer's fail.

Comment: TcpListener is a helper class meant to make it easy to implement a TCP server.  IDisposable never once made anything easy.  Not disposing a socket is *not* a grave problem, it uses very few system resources.  Its finalizer can do the job just fine.  Especially so in a simple scenario where TcpListener is appropriate, the kind of program that creates a listener just once and have it live for the life of the process.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: @HansPassant: Failure to dispose a socket may cause excessive resource consumption on whatever far-end machine is hosting the socket.  If that far end machine is a small embedded micro, its usefulness could be severely impaired until the finalizer runs or its network socket times out.

Comment: That's nonsensical FUD, use the Stop() method.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use the `IPEndPoint` based [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4zw1w3a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `TcpListener` doesn't own the socket. It would be very rude to dispose of said socket if you planned on reusing said `IPEndPoint` object